# How to create a tar file without the top directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command, tar

I am trying to tar files from a directory using the following command:

```
tar -cvzf archive.tgz -C /tmp/sjohal/okay .
```

However I don't want my tar file to contain the top line "./"
As seen in the output below:

```
drwxrwx--- cfes/cfes         0 2015-05-21 12:24:53 ./
-rw-rw---- cfes/cfes         0 2015-05-21 12:24:53 ./file3
-rw-rw---- cfes/cfes         0 2015-05-21 12:24:48 ./file1
-rw-rw---- cfes/cfes         0 2015-05-21 12:24:52 ./file2
```

How can I tar a file without the top line being added in "./" ?

Comment: You just want to tar the files from the directory but not the directory himself ?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can avoid this.  The files from the current directory will always be in "./".  What you can control is whether or not the full path will be honored (/tmp/sjohal/okay vs ./sjohal/okay, for instance).  GNU Tar will not honor a full path by default but will translate it to be relative unless you override it.

Comment: I  agree with David and in your case, it's must be better to add files one per one in your tar file, without give the path of the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think you can do this while using `-C`. (`-C` has some very severe limitations in my usage.)

I think you need to use something like this instead:

```
(dir=$PWD; shopt -s nullglob; cd /tmp/sjohal/okay && tar -czvf $dir/archive.tgz .[!.]* ..?* *)
```

- `.[!.]*` matches files with a leading single dot followed by anything that isn't a dot.
- `..?*` matches files with two leading dots and at least one other character.
- `*` matches all normal (non-dot) files.

Alternatively, you could post-process the tarball to delete the `./` entry if that's all you want to fix.